# Cannot Resize Events in react-big-calendar with dragAndDrop addon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I've implemented the onEventResize method that is supposed to handle the event resize but it doesn't seem to get triggered.

All of my events have the isResizable property set to true.

Is there something that I'm missing to make the event resizing work?

heres how im calling the calendar:

```
<CalendarResizable
  localizer={localizer}
  events={events}
  startAccessor="start"
  endAccessor="end"
  selectable
  defaultView="week"
  views={['week']}
  components={scheduleType === 'fixed' ? { toolbar: CustomToolbar } : {}}
  formats={scheduleType === 'fixed' ? fixedFormats : flexFormats}
  min={moment('8:00am', 'h:mma').toDate()}
  max={moment('7:00pm', 'h:mma').toDate()}
  timeslots={2}
  onDoubleClickEvent={handleDoubleClickEvent}
  onEventDrop={moveEvent}
  onEventResize={resizeEvent}
  onSelectSlot={newEvent}
  resizable
  draggableAccessor="isDraggable"
  resizableAccessor="isResizable"
/>
```

my calendar is imported like:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control */
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer, Navigate } from 'react-big-calendar';
import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop';
import moment from 'moment';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

const CalendarResizable = withDragAndDrop(Calendar);
```